# How do I expect an HTTP request NOT to be made?

Tags: angularjs, httpbackend

Angular's [$httpBackend service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) lets you expect an HTTP request with `expectGET`, `expectPOST`, etc. (or just `expect`).

How would I write a test that says, "the controller should NOT make a request to this endpoint (under these conditions)"?

I was thinking something like:

```
$httpBackend.when('/forbidden/endpoint').respond(function() {
  throw Error("Shouldn't be making a request to /forbidden/endpoint!");
});
```

That seems a *bit* hacky to me, but I'm fine with it if that's the normal way to do things. (But I doubt that.)

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution. Did you find one?

Comment: I thought about it and I think I found a good solution I guess. Answer is following

Answer (score 12):

I stumbled over the same issue.

The solution would be to have a callback function as response and inside you could `expect(true).toBe(false)` or in my opinion something a little bit more beautiful:

```
it ('should not trigger HTTP request', function() {
    var forbiddenCallTriggered = false;
    $httpBackend
      .when('/forbidden/endpoint')
      .respond(function() {
        forbiddenCallTriggered = true;
        return [400, ''];
      });

    // do whatever you need to call.

    $rootScope.$digest();
    $httpBackend.flush();

    // Let test fail when request was triggered.
    expect(forbiddenCallTriggered).toBe(false);
  });
```

Comment: When running that I get a `Error: No pending request to flush !` error

Comment: `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest` might help achieve what you need

Comment: Using `$rootScope.$digest()` _without_ `$httpBackend.flush()` solved the `No pending request to flush` error for me.

Answer (score 5):

For scenarios like this I often use [Jasmine's spyOn()](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies) function. You can spy on functions of `$http`, `$resource`, or of a custom service (like `myServiceThatUsesHTTP` below):

```
spyOn(myServiceThatUsesHTTP, 'query');
// test, then verify:
expect(myServiceThatUsesHTTP.query).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
// or
expect(myServiceThatUsesHTTP.query.callCount).toBe(0);
```

When you `spyOn()` a function, the original function is replaced. The code for the original function is not executed, which can be good or bad (depending on what you need to do for the test).

For example, if you need the `$promise` object that $http or $resource returns, you can do this:

```
spyOn($http, '$get').andCallThrough();
```

Comment: I considered this as well, but it seems a bit fragile, doesn't it? It might happen that the calling code subtly changes so not exactly the same method is called, but the HTTP request still gets made. Or maybe that's a contrived scenario that wouldn't actually happen; I don't know.

Comment: Yeah good point. I don't think it's necessarily a contrived scenario. I'm coding such a test right now and now you've got me thinking twice :)

Comment: To me I consider your solution safe enough ;) Just a typo correction anyway, it's ".and.callThrough();" rather than camel case "andCallThrough()"

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be to check if `$httpBackend.flush()` throws an exception, since there should be nothing to flush:

```
beforeEach(function() {
   $httpBackend.whenGET('/forbidden/endpoint');
   ...
   // call service method under test (that should not make $http call)
});

it('Should not call the endpoint', function() {
    expect($httpBackend.flush).toThrow();
});
```

Important thing to note: we use `when` and not `expect`, since we don't actually expect the call to be made. And since there is no call, `$httpBackend.flush()` will throw an exception: No pending request to flush.

Answer (score 0):

`$httpBackend` is not applied because the `$http` call doesn't get made in this test.

Instead, you can inject `$http` in your test, and then `spyOn()` `$http` directly:

```
beforeEach(fn () { 
  inject(function ($injector) {
    this.service = $injector.get('serviceOrControllerOrDirectiveBeingTested');
    this.$http = $injector.get('$http');
  }
});
```

and then

```
it('should ...', fn() {
  spyOn(this.$http, 'get');
  this.service.methodThatTriggersTheHttpCall();
  expect(this.$http.get).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```